# What is the best way to display results and data coming from Database in PHP web applications?

Tags: php, database, list, report

What is the best way to display results and data coming from Database in PHP web applications?

Is it Using HTML Tables or HTML Lists or HTML Forms or User-defined Reports? What is the common way that Most PHP Developers and programmers used?

Is there any fast or simple way to do that without the need to customize every output data structure used with every specific web page?

Comment: That really depends on your needs. What form do you need to show the data in?

Comment: You have to understand that your question is not PHP or database related. but it's just about HTML. And I cant see you accepted any answer to your old question. will you? try to be nice yourself first. it seems you want to be a leech and troll without paying back even a bit.

Comment: Best way to display them is on the screen - I've found writing an scribing application using quill and ink to be irksome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it Using HTML Tables or HTML Lists or HTML Forms or User-defined Reports ?

- Use tables if you have tabular data
- Use lists if you have list data
- Never use forms, since forms are for input *not* output

In short — use the HTML with the semantics that best fit the document (i.e. exactly the same as any other web page).

As for user-defined reports. That's a fairly vague term. If you mean "Allow users to determine which data is displayed", then that has nothing to do with how you express that data. If you mean "Allow users to upload templates", then you'll need to do a fair amount of work to protect yourself (and other users) from malicious templates and to educate users in how to create them.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your needs. You can use the table or Div or JavaScript libraries.